# Clearing fields at the touch of a button

Tags: html, reactjs, input-field

I have fields of auto-completion. When I press a button I want to clear the existing data and get clean fields.

I did this and it does not work:

```
      <Autocomplete
            id="combo-box-demo"
            value={searchCases.NAME}
            options={Cases}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.NAME.toString()}
            style={{ width: 200 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField {...params} label="name" variant="outlined" />
            )}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.innerText, "L_C_NUM")}
          />
        <Autocomplete
            id="combo-box-demo"
            value={searchCases.AGE}
            options={Cases}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.AGE.toString()}
            style={{ width: 200 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField {...params} label="age" variant="outlined" />
            )}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.innerText, "AGE")}
          />
```

That's the clean button

```
              <Button onClick={() => handleReset()}>נקה נתונים</Button>
```

And that's the function:

```
     const handleReset = () => {
    setSearchCases({});
  };

    useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(searchCases);

  },[searchCases])
```

Comment: What does console.log(searchCases); print?

Comment: I get a full object
Not an empty object as expected

Comment: I think you should add your useState hook for searchCases. If the component code is not that large, maybe add the whole component here. Btw Is your <Button> a custom button?

Comment: I have a lot of fields for autocomplete